# How do I add a system-wide environment variable for my software?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, software-installation

How can I set an system-wide environment variable for my software installation such that all users will inherit it?

I only need to be compatible with both CentOS 7+ and Fedora 30+, as this is what I'm using locally, but I would like to know what my options are for other distros.

This is to be added to a a simple makefile that is using rsync to install to `$(PREFIX)/lib/library_name/` with su/sudo permissions at the time of installation.

Comment: That last bit makes no sense to me. What is to be added ta the Makefile? Why is your Makefile using `rsync` as root to install things, and why are you bringing attention to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/profile.d/` is a good place to put your application specific setups.
`/etc/profile` loads profiles from `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

This is better than modifying `/etc/profile` itself because it avoids being overwritten by system updates. It's **system-wide** and works for most distributions.